OpenFeign fallback issue: All downstream calls fallback when only one service is down
I'm facing difficulties with openfeign fallback while implementing an MSA project.
My post-service exposes an endpoint to retrieve a specific post.
In the method mapped to that endpoint, requests are sent to the user-service and comment-service using OpenFeign, and the responses from these services (the author of the post and the list of comments attached to it) are used to provide the post details.
@GetMapping("/{postId}")
    public ResponseEntity<PostResponse> getPost(@PathVariable Long postId) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Post post = postService.getPost(postId);
        User user = userService.getUserInfoByUserId(post.getUserId());
        List<Comment> comments = commentService.getComments(postId);

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .cacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS).cachePublic())
                .body(new PostResponse(post, user.getName(), comments));
    }

However, when I intentionally stop the user-service and send a request to retrieve a specific post, I’ve found that both userClientFallback and commentClientFallback are triggered.
My expected response is that only userClientFallback would be triggered, resulting in the author being null.
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserClient userClient;

    public User getUserInfoByUserId(Long userId) {
        return userClient.getUserInfoByUserId(userId);
    }
}

@FeignClient(name = "user-service", fallback = UserClientFallback.class)
public interface UserClient {
    @GetMapping(value = "/api/users/{userId}",headers = "User-Agent=FeignClient")
    User getUserInfoByUserId(@PathVariable Long userId);
}

@Component
public class UserClientFallback implements UserClient {
    @Override
    public User getUserInfoByUserId(Long userId) {
        System.out.println("user fallback!");
        return new User();
    }
}


@Service
public class CommentService {

    @Autowired
    private CommentClient commentClient;

    public List<Comment> getComments(Long postId) {
        return commentClient.getComments(postId);
    }
}

@FeignClient(name = "comment-service", fallback = CommentClientFallback.class)
public interface CommentClient {
    @GetMapping("/api/posts/{postId}/comments")
    List<Comment> getComments(@PathVariable Long postId);
}

@Component
public class CommentClientFallback implements CommentClient {
    @Override
    public List<Comment> getComments(Long postId) {
        System.out.println("comment fallback!");
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}


These settings are applied to the user-service, post-service, and comment-service alike. I have also installed the resilience4j dependency.
cloud:
    openfeign:
      circuitbreaker:
        enabled: true

I tried making changes like this, but it had no effect.
 @GetMapping("/{postId}")
    public ResponseEntity<PostResponse> getPost(@PathVariable Long postId) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Post post = postService.getPost(postId);        
        CompletableFuture<User> userFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> userService.getUserInfoByUserId(post.getUserId()));
        User user = userFuture.get();
        CompletableFuture<List<Comment>> commentsFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> commentService.getComments(postId));
        List<Comment> comments = commentsFuture.get();

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .cacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS).cachePublic())
                .body(new PostResponse(post, user.getName(), comments));
    }

I’m using that version.
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.5'
set('springCloudVersion', "2023.0.3")

Please help me resolve this issue.

Have you setup client side load balancing?
